# Reconstruct a complete tree given the in-order traversal

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

A complete binary tree is a tree in which all levels are full except the last one, in which we start filling in from the left. Is there any recursive procedure to reconstruct a complete tree given the in-order traversal?

Edit: so far I concluded

```
if (nr_nodes - (2^nr_complete_levels - 1) <= 2^(nr_complete_levels - 1))
  then root_index is nr_nodes - (2^(nr_complete_levels - 1) - 1)
    else root_index is 2^nr_complete_levels
```

Now the idea can be applied recursively as suggested. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You need to compute the index of the root in the in-order array. Place the root into the tree. Then you've got two smaller arrays that represent the left and right subtrees. Recurse. So your task is to figure out how to calculate the index of the root from length of the array.

Comment: In response to the edit: If you're using 1-based indexing, then yes, that appears to be correct.

Comment: @user3386109 that's correct. It's just the idea. Still have to implement it.

Comment: Well done, carry on :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is definitely a way to solve this problem recursively. Since it is a complete tree, then every subtree in this tree is a complete tree. And since it is a complete tree, you can know the exact structure of the tree, and knowing this allows you to know the indices of the roots of the subtrees in the array. And then the subproblems become reconstructing the left subtree and right subtree. Basically, you could have a pointer initialized to the 0th index position of the array, and traverse the array using that pointer and at the same time build the tree. When that global pointer is pointed to the root index, create the root, connect its left pointer to the left subtree built, increment the pointer, recursively call this function to build the right subtree, and connect its right pointer to the right subtree built.